# Make a String Literal Types from an Array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have this object in my definition files

```js
export const properties = {
  name: '',
  level: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  uri: '',
  active: true
}
```

(note: it's not an interface it's actually a real object, the reason I need an object is because I need it as a reference during runtime)

Now I try to make a type from this object, so this is what I need

```js
export type Properties = {
  name: string;
  level: 'a'|'b'|'c';
  uri: string;
  active: boolean
}
```

I tried using

```
export type Properties = typeof properties
```

but `level` is translated as `string[]` which is normal, but how can I use TypeScript to map `['a', 'b', 'c']` to `'a'|'b'|'c'` ? And if it's possible how can I do that during the mapping of one type to another?

Thanks

Comment: Terminology issue: you are talking about [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types), not [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types).

Comment: @jcalz thanks. Title updated.

Comment: It looks like you want `properties` to have type `Properties`. But in `properties` the type of `level` is a list of strings, while in `Properties` it's just a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define `properties` exactly as you've done above, then it won't work. By the time you get around to writing `type Properties =`, the compiler has already widened the `level` property to `string[]`, and forgotten all about the [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) of its elements, as you've seen.

In order to even have a chance to get `"a" | "b" | "c"` out of `properties`, therefore, you will need to alter the definition of `properties`.  The easiest way is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to give the compiler a hint that you want the narrowest type it can infer.  For example:

```
const properties = {
    name: '',
    level: ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const,
    uri: '',
    active: true
}
```

We've asserted `level` as `const`, and now `typeof properties` looks like this:

```
/* const properties: {
    name: string;
    level: readonly ["a", "b", "c"];
    uri: string;
    active: boolean;
} */
```

So, how can we transform that to get `Properties`?  Assuming the question "how can I do that during the mapping of one type to another?" means you'd like every array-like thing to be transformed to its element type, and assuming that you only need to do this one-level deep (and not recursively), then you can define this type function:

```
type Transform<T> = { [K in keyof T]: 
  T[K] extends readonly any[] ? T[K][number] : T[K] 
}
```

That's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) where we take the input type `T`, and for each property key `K`, we [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get its property type (`T[K]`).  If that property type is not an array (`readonly any[]` is actually more general than `any[]`), we leave it alone.  If it *is* an array, then we grab its element type by indexing into it with `number` (if you have an array `arr` and a number `n`, then `arr[n]` will be an element).

For `typeof properties`, that results in:

```
type Properties = Transform<typeof properties>
/* type Properties = {
    name: string;
    level: "a" | "b" | "c";
    uri: string;
    active: boolean;
} */
```

as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7zFCZiwJbCpwC8cA3gLABQctcyAhgLbABccA5BwDTV1wAbYADdgA9gG0ODHpwBGsjgg4BdOAyJI0MXjToBXKHnZdd-Bghh5R7GFH3BqAX2oB6AFSIU6OJmy4rQnZKPVpGFnZ0I2QAcwBuPjohUXE4KGAGABMUAQBPOAkAIgZC7jhCuVLyhEKVBNC4Q2M4KLxY+vNLazY4OQgIIQZkeqc4d1dqahhcnDgAFSgh1AAzaCYAHjmAPhJyAoBpODa4AGtgXIhl+ZV2OYl9tVAYYGRMonSsnPyh3Ik1AH55vcVBJkPomHJcGpbsC4C4qFMZsA4AAFLA4fCEXYLJarKAbaY4S6+dEBAioLZuTyE5Fo-yYoikEL8cI9VrtRK0ZJidjFQpwAA+5UqguqhQ6BiMkTsbXinPUXRsvX6g2GzjGriAA)

Comment: What a beautiful answer, not only you share very advanced knowledge but also you took the time to explain how things work in a very well arranged way. Not only It now works but I also know why. Very well appreciated @jcalz Thanks